# django - having some issue serving static_url files, but media_url works ok

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates, static-files

I've this in my urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
handler404 = 'views.custom_404'
handler500 = 'views.custom_500'
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "media")

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "static_root")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "static_files"),
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

I've this in wsgi.py

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ecommerce.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Eveything works fine when in development when DEBUG & TEMPLATE_DEBUG is set to True. Once set to FALSE, I can only see static files on the site.

For example this static loads

```
    src="/static/img/placeholder.svg"
```

but this media doesn't

```
    src="/media/foodtruck/logo/banner2.jpg"
```

The folders are set up as such

```
root\static\media\foodtruck\logo\banner2.jpg

root\static\static_root\img\placeholder.svg
```

in html

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ truck.logo }}">
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/placeholder.svg">
```

Answer (score 0):

`STATIC_ROOT` is only used in a non-DEBUG environment, you should let your webserver figure out where you static files are in production and collect files accordingly using the `collectstatic` management command, here's an apache example

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/example.com/static/

<Directory /var/www/example.com/static>
    Options -Indexes
    Order Deny,Allow
</Directory>
```

n.b. there's no need to use the prefixes in templates using the static tag

`{% static "img/foo.jpg" %}`

Comment: thanks for that. The static files works fine. I'm more concerned about the media files. How is it that static gets served but not media? I'm using heroku.